# How to color text to later be put in a docx file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-docx, termcolor

I want to color a text present in the string and pass the string to another python file so that to put received colored string into a docx file. I tried in this way but it is not working.

```
from termcolor import colored
from docx import Document

document = Document()
item_i="\n\n Comma is required in line dependent clause is in beginning\n\n" 
ctxt = colored(item_i, 'blue')
p=document.add_paragraph()
p.add_run(ctxt)
document.add_page_break()

document.save('demo.docx')
```

it displays properly in terminal but not in file, it shows an error

```
from termcolor import colored

item_i="\n\n Comma is required in line dependent clause is in beginning\n\n" 
ctxt = colored(item_i, 'blue')
print ctxt
```

In this format it displays properly. Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I guess termcolor can color chars on a terminal. And I guess docx has something to do with microsoft word format. The two are unrelated. Coloring on a terminal is coded completely different from coloring chars in ms word.

Comment: yes but i want to do the same thing on a file

Comment: Do you mean a file meant to be opened in msword or to be printed on a terminal (black console window)

Comment: I want to print that in ms word

Comment: txt file can also work but docx is more preferred

Comment: I think it will work in a txt file if you just echo it to the console. But using termcolor.colored will never work in .docx format for ms-word. A simple workaround is to produce a better documented, simpler format like HTML, which you can load into msword. You don't need to import termcolor or docs to do that.

Comment: I have learnt from this question, as well as, from the comments and answer to it. I don't know why some smart people have down-voted this question! I always though that the zeal to self assure has a huge preponderence among people of mediocrity like me. Somehow, smart people are displaying this unique idiosyncrasy all across stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `docx`'s text formatting since, as Jacques de Hooge said, `termcolor` is for terminal. See [here](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html#apply-character-formatting).

```
from docx.shared import RGBColor
```

Then

```
run = p.add_run(item_i)
run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x00, 0x00, 0xFF)
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I've tried this also but I've to return the changes made in string to another file so that file can put the string into docx file.  I mean when I give return item_i or run the changes made is to be there.

Comment: I'm new to python that's why I'm having these types of doubts.

Comment: Not sure what you mean--do you need to read a string from a text file and write it to the docx file?

Comment: no i just want to write a string in which some of the text is colored and pass the string to another python file which creates a docx file of passed string.

Comment: Why do you want to pass it to another file? You want to put this functionality in a different module?